# Unable to play Android VideoView in fullscreen mode.

Tags: android

In my project i am taking a linearlayout of width and height as full_parent and to that I am adding a VideoView of width and height as fill_parent but the video is not occupying entire screen.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In XML try defining your VideoView as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<VideoView android:id="@+id/videoView1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"></VideoView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: ya i tried like that also but i didnot get the expected result. thanks for responding

Comment: put your xml code in question so other can get to know what you are trying and can help you

Answer (score 0):

Put This Code before SetContentView in Your Activity

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

I think it may help You.